# Does there exist a poem that uses direction to change its meaning?

Tags: ambiguity, poetry

I've been reading about writing order and the question has been poking at me for a while now: **since writing order could theoretically introduce ambiguity, is it possible that someone has written a poem that reads differently depending on the direction it's read in?**

For example, read left-to-right, it would mean one thing, while read top-down, it would mean something entirely different.

```
~` ~` ~` ~` ~` ~` ~`
+- +- +- +- +- +- +-
=_ =_ =_ =_ =_ =_ =_
```

In this pretend language that's supposed to represent Japanese, the poem would read:

```
~` ~` ~` ~` ~` ~` ~` +- +- +- +- +- +- +- =_ =_ =_ =_ =_ =_ =_
A frog jumped into a pot of boiling water and jumped back out.
```

or top-down:

```
~` +- =_ ~` +- =_ ~` +- =_ ~` +- =_ ~` +- =_ ~` +- =_ ~` +- =_
A man went to the deli to buy some ham.
```

---

Edit:

Someone provided an [interesting example](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B8%A6%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF) (now deleted), so I thought I should add this in, since it's probably the reason they deleted their answer:

[**addendum**] I'm thinking about an example that reads in both directions in full, rather than being "Bible code" or the peppering of a message within a larger text. I did not have the following in mind:

```
In a small town, there liveD a man who, despIte his lOw inTellect, was loved 
by many. He was an...
```

Or

```
I apologize for my rudeness, but I don't quite think YOU know what 
you ARE talking about. Stupidity comes in many forms, not just A poorly 
developed intellect. This common assumption tends to JERK those in the know.
```

Rather, something like

```
I   l i k e   f o o d
n   i c i v   o n n i
    m a l e   r l o n
a   b r l r   g y m n
    o u e y   e   o e
s   , s d o   t k p r
t     ,   n   f n o 
a   t   a e   u o t
g   h v l     l w o
n   e i l     , s e
a     o           i
n   m l o     h a a
t   a e f     e b "
    n n         o ,
    , t         u
      l         t h
      y           e
                "
                  h
                  a
                  d
```

Pretending for the moment that the vertical passage makes any sense and that "n iciv onni", etc, are English words. Think "crossword puzzle"

Comment: Orthographically, I think this is going to be much more common in Chinese than Japanese.

Comment: Someone linked to [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B8%A6%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF), but then they deleted their answer. While it wasn't *exactly* what I was thinking about (it's more akin to "bible code", or the hiding of a message by peppering it within a larger text), it was still an interesting read. It also led to a rather amusing article about [a certain English word](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ファック)

Comment: 電車の中で書きかけてたんですが時間がなかったので一旦消しました…ごめんなさい

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example of a block of text which is *fully* understandable both vertically and horizontally, is from this comedy. (And I'm afraid I know nothing more complex or sophisticated than this.)

極秘情報 (Top Secret) performed by アンジャッシュ
https://youtu.be/n5JfsbM89v8

```
ワタシ
カツラ
ナノダ
シカモ
ゲイ○
```

"モ○" at the bottom right is actually a kanji number 一七〇 (170) written vertically, and "一七" looks like katakana モ.

When read vertically, "シラダ" (whose height is 170cm), "タツノ カイ" and "ワカナ シゲ" are three typical Japanese names.

When read horizontally, it reads "私カツラなのだ　しかもゲイ。" (I wear a wig, and furthermore, I'm gay).

---

"Bible Code" type wordplay is much more common, and it probably exists from ancient times. Some people believe that [いろは歌](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroha), which was created as early as the 10th or 11th century, has [such a code](http://www.geocities.jp/yasuko8787/z029.htm).

Today this kind of wordplay is called [縦読み](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E7%B8%A6%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF), and you can find new 縦読み created every day in forums like 2ちゃんねる. Recently newspapers often have [wonderful 縦読み in TV guide pages](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2134492560702759201).

Comment: あ、そういえばドラマのTRICKでそういうのでてきたっけ・・・思い出せない・・ Edit これこれ　http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1440607169

Comment: こういうかんじ　http://community.img.mixi.jp/photo/comm/67/86/1046786_231.jpg

Comment: 「テ・ハイ」が苦しいｗ　こういうの、稀に見ることある気がしますけど、特に一般的な名前はないですよね。

Comment: そおですねえ、行頭と行末だけならdouble acrosticなんでしょうが、それ以上は・・・

Comment: I'm still a beginner in Japanese, so I can't understand anything you're saying aside from the occasional number, "watashi (私) (me/I)", or "go (語) (language)" kanji. Google translate is coming up with garbage, so I appreciate the explanation, and this is a fascinating example (have an accept). I'm making some rapid progress, though. Still learning to read kana, and I got "a n zhi y? (j? (?)) sshi ?" from "アンジャッシュ", "Watashi ka tsu ? ? no da shi ka m? ? i." from "私カツラなのだ　しかもゲイ。", "i ro ha ?" from "いろは歌", and "2 chi-ya (cha) n ? ru" from " 2ちゃんねる". Some kana are really hard to remember, like ね.

Comment: Also, I'm happy to say that I figured out the difference between so/n and shi/tsu. So's smaller mark "points" downward, while n "points" to the right, and shi aligns at the left, while tsu aligns at the top, such that shi appears to be "looking up", while tsu appears to "look down". Or as someone else put it, "shi is always looking up at tsu".

Comment: @B1KMusic If you're just starting out, poems alone would be hard, but something like what you're asking for is almost certain to end up with some really tough Japanese... certainly not beginner material.

Comment: P.S., once you learn Japanese do go check out everything by アンジャッシュ. They are hilarious.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I dunno why, but I like to delve right into the most difficult/ambiguous examples of a given topic that I can find, regardless of my skill level, to test the boundaries and know the limits for extreme cases. I like finding glitches in video games, playing the hardest difficulty to know how hard it can get, testing bizarre edge cases in programming languages, and of course, finding poems like the above, or [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion-Eating_Poet_in_the_Stone_Den), [2](http://pastebin.com/M7wWxq82), [3](http://pastebin.com/mcsftGWz).

Comment: The reason is because if I'm a newbie, I get to see what I'm in for, and if I'm experienced, it's a good challenge to see how skilled I've become. How far can I get in I Wanna Be The Guy on Impossible mode? (Incidentally, mecha-birdo), How many times can I nest command substitutions / math expressions in the bash shell? How many loops can I nest in brainfuck before it becomes too difficult to keep track of? How many ways can I segfault in C? What's the most minimalistic way to write a text file? (so far, `cat > file`, then the contents, then `^D`)